# Populated dropdown how to get value?

Tags: php, mysql

how to get the value of selected in php populated from mysql database

```
//function for dropdown

function getDropDown( $name, $table, $code, $desc )
{
  $query = "SELECT $code, $desc FROM $table";  
  echo "<select name=\"$name\">";
  echo '<option> Select One </option>';
  connect(); //connects to mysql 
  $result = mysql_query( $query );`enter code here`
  if( !$result )  die ( "error" . mysql_error() );
  $foundRows = mysql_numrows ( $result );
   //loop to populate dropdown
  for( $row = 0; $row < $foundRows; ++$row)
  {
    list( $c, $d ) = mysql_fetch_row( $result );
    echo "<option name= value=\"$c\">$d</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
}
```

to use selected?

Comment: please clarify... what do you mean by "get the value if sekected"? are you trying to set the default value on the `<select>` you want to get the selected `<option>` after the form submit? you want to set an specific `value` attribute on the `>option>` tag?

Comment: my problem is that when i used $_POST['$NAME'] i dont get the posted value or sometimes the value turns '' ;

Comment: Note that this kind of problem sometimes points to bad (and vulnerable) design!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getDropDown( $name, $table, $code, $desc )
{
  $query = "SELECT $code, $desc FROM $table";  
  echo "<select name=\"$name\">";
  echo '<option> Select One </option>';
  connect(); //connects to mysql 
  $result = mysql_query( $query );`enter code here`
  if( !$result )  die ( "error" . mysql_error() );
  $foundRows = mysql_numrows ( $result );
   //loop to populate dropdown
  for( $row = 0; $row < $foundRows; ++$row)
  {
    list( $c, $d ) = mysql_fetch_row( $result );
    echo "<option name= value=\"$c\" if($_POST['value']==database_value) { 'selected'; }>$d</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
}
```

**if($_POST['value']==database_value) { "selected" }**

This is the change

Answer (score 0):

You will get in POST or GET array key with name $name and value of selected $c.
So if $name = "pickwinner" and selected item will have value $c = 'Anna', then you get in $_POST or $_GET (depending on your form setting) array('pickwinner'=>'anna')

Answer (score 0):

$name you given to your select box, after posting the form you can retrieve the value either by $_POST[$name] if your form methos is set to PST and $_GET[$name] if your form method is set to GET. this is really simple

Comment: i did use the value $POST[$NAME] but the value is  ''

Comment: $name value in $_POST[$name] is same as you are using in your form? and also it is $_POST means you are missing _

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

//function for dropdown

```
function getDropDown( $name, $table, $code, $desc, $val='')
{
  $query = "SELECT $code, $desc FROM $table";  
  echo "<select name=\"$name\">";
  echo '<option> Select One </option>';
  connect(); //connects to mysql 
  $result = mysql_query( $query );`enter code here`
  if( !$result )  die ( "error" . mysql_error() );
  $foundRows = mysql_numrows ( $result );
  //loop to populate dropdown
  $sel = '';
  for( $row = 0; $row < $foundRows; ++$row)
  {
    if($val == $c)
        $sel = 'selected="selected"';
    list( $c, $d ) = mysql_fetch_row( $result );
    echo "<option ".$sel." name= value=\"$c\">$d</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
```

1) I ahve added fifth parameter, you need to pass it to get selected.

2) if($val == $c) uses to apply selected attribute

3) $sel used inside your option creation.

Check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Instruction:

Compare database value with Combo Box option value.
If both are equal then set "SELECTED" value in php variable otherwise set it to BLANK.
In last, use that variable in option tag.